# Remove highlight in printed quoted line

Tags: color, highlighting

In some journal, they required changes made to be highlighted in some striking color. Then, the revised paragraph also need to be reflected in the reply to reviewer section. 
The tex below should do this task in one pass.

However, it seems the quote macro copy together the color formatting into the reply-to-reviewer section.
I really appreciate if someone can share what is the best way to remove the highlighted text in the section: Response to reviewer?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{framed} % to add frames around comments
\usepackage{parskip} % to skip paragraph indentation
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk} % for title page
\usepackage{lineno}\linenumbers % add line numbers to whole document
\usepackage{hyperref} % to enable hyperlinks
\usepackage{fullpage} % less white margin space



% line referencing
\newcommand{\R}[1]{\label{#1}\linelabel{#1}} % use this to set the placement of the line reference tags 
\newcommand{\lr}[1]{page~\pageref{#1}, line~\lineref{#1}} % use this to reference the tags (print line numbers)

% quoting
\newcommand\declquotedtext[2]{\expandafter\def\csname quotedtext@#1 \endcsname{#2}} %use around text you may want to quote later, but don't want printed in the main text
\newcommand\defquotedtext[2]{\declquotedtext{#1}{#2}#2} %use around text you want to appear in the main text and that you want to quote later
\newcommand\usequotedtext[1]{\csname quotedtext@#1 \endcsname} %use to print the quoted text

\newcommand{\q}[1]{``#1''} % easier way to get double quotes


\usepackage{color, soul}
\sethlcolor{yellow}

\newcommand {\rrb}[4]{\R{#1}\defquotedtext{#2}{\hl{#3}}\R{#4}}


\begin{document}




\section*{Revised draft}


\rrb{01st}{R1-001}{Test answer revised draft}{01Finish}

\nolinenumbers
\section*{Response to reviewer comments}

\begin{framed}Line 21: Rephrase sentence to be less informal\end{framed}
Response: Rephrased sentence to increase formality. Sentence now reads: \q{\usequotedtext{R1-001}} (\lr{01st} to \lr{01Finish}). %

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you still have the original then you could use [latexdiff](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{framed} % to add frames around comments
\usepackage{parskip} % to skip paragraph indentation
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk} % for title page
\usepackage{lineno}\linenumbers % add line numbers to whole document
\usepackage{hyperref} % to enable hyperlinks
\usepackage{fullpage} % less white margin space
% line referencing
\newcommand{\R}[1]{\label{#1}\linelabel{#1}} % use this to set the placement of the line reference tags 
\newcommand{\lr}[1]{page~\pageref{#1}, line~\lineref{#1}} % use this to reference the tags (print line numbers)
% quoting
\newcommand\declquotedtext[2]{\expandafter\def\csname quotedtext@#1 \endcsname{#2}} %use around text you may want to quote later, but don't want printed in the main text
\newcommand\defquotedtext[2]{\declquotedtext{#1}{#2}#2} %use around text you want to appear in the main text and that you want to quote later
\newcommand\usequotedtext[1]{\csname quotedtext@#1 \endcsname} %use to print the quoted text
\newcommand{\q}[1]{``#1''} % easier way to get double quotes

%Alternative 1%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\ans}[1]{\sethlcolor{white}``#1''} % easier way to get double quotes without yellow hlight

\usepackage{color, soul}
\sethlcolor{yellow}
\newcommand {\rrb}[4]{\R{#1}\defquotedtext{#2}{\hl{#3}}\R{#4}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Revised draft}

\rrb{01st}{R1-001}{Test answer revised draft}{01Finish}

\nolinenumbers
\section*{Response to reviewer comments}

\begin{framed}Line 21: Rephrase sentence to be less informal\end{framed}
Response: Rephrased sentence to increase formality. Sentence now reads: as was \q{\usequotedtext{R1-001}} (\lr{01st} to \lr{01Finish}). 


\textbf{Alternative 1}
\hrule
Response: Rephrased sentence to increase formality. Sentence now reads: using re definition \ans{\usequotedtext{R1-001}} (\lr{01st} to \lr{01Finish}). %

\textbf{Alternative 2}
\hrule
Response: Rephrased sentence to increase formality. Sentence now reads: manual intervention \q{\sethlcolor{white}\usequotedtext{R1-001}} (\lr{01st} to \lr{01Finish}). %

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks KJO, really appreciate it